# how to replace values in innerhtml using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace, innerhtml

I'm dynamically(on click of radio button) copying the inner html of one row(in a table) to other but after removing some elements.

```
var a = document.getElementById('copyrow' + e).innerHTML;
a = a.replace('<input type="radio" name="selectradio" id="shareredio"+e "" a="" href="#" onclick="setText("+e");">',"")
    .replace('<div class="custom-radio" style="margin-top:50px;">',"")
    .replace('<label for="shareredio"+e""></label>',"")
    .replace('<input type="checkbox" name="sharecheck" id="sharecheck"+e"">',"")
    .replace('<label for="sharecheck"+e""></label>',"")
    .replace('Share fare',"");

document.getElementById('copyDiv').innerHTML = a;
```

I don't know enough about javascript but if there is any better way then please help...

Comment: You could remove the elements from the DOM instead of doing so many replacements. Also, your HTML string would appear to have a *lot* of concatenation issues.

Comment: thank you... :) @Rory McCrossan
but may i know how...
the +e is a dynamically generated variable for different rows

Comment: Your method is not durable. I agree with @Rory. You should make use of DOM to manipulate your elements. It's way more efficient and tracable.

Comment: Why do people down vote when i said I don't know enough about javascript, I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the best way to do it but I thought I'd at least give you an answer quickly. This is using jQuery to manipulate the DOM.

```
var $a = $('#copyrow'+e).clone();
$a.find('input#shareredio'+e).remove();
$a.find('div.custom-radio').remove();
$a.find('label[for="shareredio'+e+'"]').remove();
$a.find('input#sharecheck'+e).remove();
$a.find('label[for="sharecheck'+e+'"]').remove();

var result = $a.html().replace('Share fare', "");

$('#copyDiv').html(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, This works fine but there is a issue. I'm copying the inner html from one table to other and your code works the way I want, but it removes the elements from the parent table too(which I don't want) , I only want to remove those elements  and copy to the child table.
Is there any solution to that too..
other than that it worked awesome

Comment: Ah right, I didn't realise that you didn't want to change the original element. In this case just add .clone() to the original selector. I've updated my answer to show you.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.copy').on('change', function(){
        if($('.copy:checked').val() == 'yes'){
            $('.table2').find('.rowContents1').html($('.table1').find('.rowContents1').html());
            $('.table2').find('.rowContents2').html($('.table1').find('.rowContents2').html());
            $('.table2').find('.rowContents3').html($('.table1').find('.rowContents3').html());
        }
        else {
            $('.table2').find('.rowContents1').html('');
            $('.table2').find('.rowContents2').html('');
            $('.table2').find('.rowContents3').html('');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
table {
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
td, th {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
div{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Copy Contents Over?<br/>
<input type="radio" class="copy" value="yes" name="copyRadio"/> Yes
<input type="radio" class="copy" value="no" name="copyRadio"/> No
<br/><br/>
<div>
    Table1
    <table class="table1">
        <header>
            <tr>
                <th>Row Number</th>
                <th>Row Contents</th>
            </tr>
        </header>
        <body>
            <tr>
                <td class="rowNum1">1</td>
                <td class="rowContents1">This is the Contents of Row 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="rowNum2">2</td>
                <td class="rowContents2">This is the Contents of Row 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="rowNum3">3</td>
                <td class="rowContents3">This is the Contents of Row 3</td>
            </tr>
        </body>
    </table>
</div>
<div>
    Table2
    <table class="table2">
        <header>
            <tr>
                <th>Row Number</th>
                <th>Row Contents</th>
            </tr>
        </header>
        <body>
            <tr>
                <td class="rowNum1">1</td>
                <td class="rowContents1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="rowNum2">2</td>
                <td class="rowContents2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="rowNum3">3</td>
                <td class="rowContents3"></td>
            </tr>
        </body>
    </table>
</div>
```

i used `.html()` to rewrite the contents inside each `td`. `.find()` function just traverses down the element tree and finds the descendants `$('.table2').find('.rowContents1')` is saying in element of class `.table2`, find the descendants with class `.rowContents1`.

hope this helps and is what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks for the solution.... But I was actually looking for something like the accepted answer.
Thanks a lot for your time and help, want to upvote this answer too but don't have enough points.